# How can I get Python to recognize the SPSSClient Module?

Tags: python, spss

I originally installed Canopy to use Python, but it would not recognize the SPSS modules, so I removed canopy, re-downloaded python2.7, and changed my PATH to ;C:\Python27. In SPSS, I changed the default python file directory to C:\Python27.

Python still will not import the SPSS modules. I have a copy of SPSS 22, so python is integrated into it...

Any thoughts on what might be causing this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out only with some help from a friend who had a similar issue. I had downloaded python from python.org, without realizing it was 32 bit. All of the SPSS modules are 64 bit! I downloaded the correct version of python, and then copied the spss modules from my spss install (inside the python folder within spss) into my python library. modules are working now!